# Is there a way to 'search n replace fill' HTML with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, search, replace

Just a small question. Say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
    {text}
</div>
```

Now we also have a JS array with 10 entries, all with a key 'text'. I want to use the snippet above as a template (snippet resides in jQuery-able webpage) for the array. Array entry goes in, HTML comes out. Here's the tricky part: I want to replace {text} with the text key from the array entry.

And all with jQuery of course ;-).

Best regards,

Reinder

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/WZ2Vk/

*(Requires jQuery 1.4 or later)*

```
var newText = {
    text: "some new text",
    othertext: "some other new text"
}

$('div.foo').text(function(i,txt) {
    var key = txt.match(/\{([^}]+)\}/)[1];
    return newText[key];
});
```

You didn't give the structure of the Array, but I assume you're using it in a manner better suited for an Object. In the example above, I used and Object instead of an Array. Will work just fine with an Array.

**Same example but with an Array:** http://jsfiddle.net/WZ2Vk/1/

If you're replacing with actual `HTML` content, then change `.text()` to `.html()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/WZ2Vk/2/